# Semantic Thumbnail Indication

Tags: html, image, semantics

Given the following link to an image:

```
<a href="path/to/img.jpg">Title</a>
```

What is the most semantically sound method for indicating the location of a thumbnail?

The best I could come up with so far is using `data-` attributes like so:

```
<a href="path/to/img.jpg" data-thumb="path/to/thumb.jpg">Title</a>
```

However, it doesn't seem very semantically sound.  Is there a better or more correct way to do this?

Comment: well, it depends on what you consider "semantic"

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an `<img>` element? You can give it a class to indicate that it's a thumbnail and hide it with progressive enhancement if you need to. That way, the thumbnail of the image will be shown in the absence of JavaScript/CSS:

```
<a href="path/to/img.jpg">
    <img src="path/to/thumbnail.jpg" class="thumb" alt="Thumbnail" />
    Title
</a>
```

Or am I being too naïve?

Comment: If thumbnail is not semantically important (it's a preview of linked resource) it should get empty alt text (alt=""). The alt attribute should be thought as replacement for the image content (it's "alternative" content after all), not a label or explanation. Use title attribute for such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="path/to/img_thumb.jpg">Title</a>
```

Simple and keeps the original path intact while just adding a suffix to indicate that the image is a thumbnail. We use this all the time on our sites and it makes things easy.

Comment: Where's the semantic relation of this link to the actual image link?